# switch between branches in egit

Tags: git, egit

I cloned a remote git repository with 10 branches. I need to work on branch but when I import, it import head. How can I switch from head branch to another branch in egit.

I did team --> switch to --> other and give branch name that I want , but it is giving me different warning message. I don't understand the whole process. I am new to git and from CVS background.

[image]

Comment: can you post the warning message here?

Comment: updated question with image

Comment: Do you want to work in the branch which is already there in the remote?

Comment: @Thiru yes that is correct.

Comment: `git checkout <branch-name>` places you in the named branch...

Comment: First thing, you have to fetch all the branch from the remote. Since you are new to git, using command line will help you understand git more. "git fetch" will help in fetching the branches from remote and "git checkout <branch name>" will help you to switch to a branch.

Comment: @vonbrand i am asking inside eclipse.

Comment: @Thiru Not what i asked for. Please read my question carefully. thanks